# How dose iter function works in python? if I do not return self in __iter__ method

Tags: python, generator, iterable, magic-methods

I create a customer iterable Class **LettersIter**, then I try to call iter with the instance of LettersIter.Then I called it twice, it return the same address in memory. But they are not the same. I am so confused about this. Why they have the same address but not the same object? And how iter works under the hood? Does it wrapper the generator function, and return the generator object, so why I call it twice and get the same address?

```py
class LettersIter:
    def __init__(self, start='a', end='e'):
        self.next_letter = start
        self.end = end

    def __next__(self):
        if self.next_letter == self.end:
            raise StopIteration
        letter = self.next_letter
        self.next_letter = chr(ord(letter)+1)
        return letter

    def __iter__(self):
        start = self.next_letter
        while start < self.end:
            yield start
            start = chr(ord(start)+1)


class Letters:
    def __init__(self, start='a', end='b'):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return LettersIter(self.start, self.end)


letter_iter = Letters('d', 'r')
first_iterator = iter(letter_iter)
print(iter(first_iterator) == iter(first_iterator))  # False
print(iter(first_iterator))  # <generator object LettersIter.__iter__ at 0x00000238211D9938>
print(iter(first_iterator))  # <generator object LettersIter.__iter__ at 0x00000238211D9938>
print(next(first_iterator))  # d
print(next(iter(first_iterator)))  # e
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to answer this.

Comment: I think that's the garbage collector or allocator reusing the same spot in memory for different instances since the old ones are deleted after each line, so if you save them in a variable somewhere you will get different memory location

Comment: The garbage collector is like "why should i free that memory if i am using it the next line, let me just put the object in the next line in the same location and save a few system calls"

Comment: @AhmedAEK greate idea, my bro. I try to save them in variables,and I get different memory location. Maybe this  is because the strategy of garbage collector. Really appreciate your reply!!!!